# Trying to access the instance variables of the class that I am calling a class method on

Tags: python

So I'm trying to access the class instance variables of the class object that I call a class method on inside the class method. I've tried `cls.__dict__` but it doesn't give me what I want. My code is just an example of the type of thing I'd like to be able to do. I would want `.save()` to print the names and values of all the instance variables in the `user` instance of the `class Users()`. I don't know if it matters but the class that I will be calling the method on will not be the same class it is defined in but one that inherits from it. Class methods are relatively new to me and I'm not 100 % comfortable with them.

```
@classmethod
 def save(cls):
     dictionary = cls.__dict__
     print (dictionary)
user = Users()
user.save()
```

Comment: Why did you mark the method `classmethod` if you want to access the data of an instance? That's what regular methods are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your method depends on having an instance, don't make it a class method.  Instead, remove the `classmethod` decorator and define `save()` as `def save(self):`.  You can then use `self.__dict__`.  Using `@classmethod` means that you are able to call the method without having an instance.  The method will be called with the class as the first argument instead.  If you need to have an instance, that decorator is counter-productive.